# Need help with regular expression for URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

Was just parsing urls of the type 
http://sitename.com/catid/300/,
http://sitename.com/catid/341/
etc etc

wherein the parameter after the catid (300,341) are only integers. When I use the following condition in .htaccess, it works fine

```
 RewriteRule ^(abc|def|hij|klm)/([0-9]+)/$ /index3.php?catid=$1&postid=$2 [L]
```

but when a php regex  match function,like preg_match, it returns 1 for alphanumeric numbers too

```
 eg: echo preg_match('([0-9]+)','a123'); or echo preg_match('([0-9]+)',a123);
```

They both return 1 ()true. I dont know why it matches alphanumerics. I want it to match only numbers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your preg_match basically boils down to "match if there's one or more digits ANYWHERE in the string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without anchors, it will match the numbers regardless of what comes before or after them. Try it with anchors:

```
/^([0-9]+)$/
```

If you don't need to capture, try this:

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

Results:

```
php > echo preg_match('([0-9]+)','a123');
1
php > echo preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/','a123');
0
php > echo preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',0.65);
0
php > echo preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',666);
1
```

Regular expressions are not always the answer. If you are just checking for a number, try [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). If you just want an integer, try [is_int](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php).

Comment: using echo preg_match('^[0-9]+$','a123');   gives this error 'No ending delimiter '^' found'

Comment: thanks bu the following case... preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',0.65); also returns true (0). :(

Comment: It worked for me. I updated the results in my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Try `preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/','a123');`

Comment: thanks mate but preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',0.65); also returns true (0).